# Copy Xcode project with watchkit to another project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I built an app that my company has for attendees to use at our 3 conferences, which I update and modify about 3 times a year for every conference we do. I usually just copy the project and make all the necessary changes to modify the project name, etc and then add whatever new features in the new project. This process has been successful for the past 3 years. However, for the last update I added the watchkit feature to the app. The problem is the usual process for copying the project and renaming it does not work as expected when copying the project with the watchkit feature. I was hoping not to have to build the watchkit extension from scratch but reuse it for my future app updates. Has anyone successfully copied a project with watchkit to a new project?

Comment: Off topic: so it's not possible to make this data-driven with a generic app being installed and the app fetching its data from a server in order to populate its contents?

Comment: The app is data-driven with it's key data and content being accessed via web services. However, 3 years ago it was a basic app and over those years each new version I incorporate at least one new feature based on feedback from attendees and staff. So although I would love for it to be generic and just update content, that's not the case.

Comment: What is the specific error message?

Comment: No errors, just crashing Xcode. The amount of time it took me to try to figure this out could have been time spent on just rebuilding the watchkit extension in the copied project and copying over the watchkit interface and implementation project files into the new watchkit folders. This is what I am doing now.